# Cannot Create Database Diagram in SQL Server 2019 Database

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2019 database that I restored from a SQL Server 2017 backup.  It has diagrams present in the System Tables dbo.sysdiagrams table, but they are not visible.  If I try to create a diagram I get an error:

[image]

What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

A shot in the dark...likely a good one.  Check the database owner to make sure it is set.  It might have been a login that is not valid on this instance.  Not having a owner can cause access issues in SSMS.

Comment: Yes! As @Randy mentioned - Check the database owner is EMPTY or Missing ? **Right Click** on Database --> **Properties** --> Select **Files** ->  Owner

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  The database owner is my Windows logon.  There is a sa account, but I don't see it in SSMS.  I can run queries in SSMS and in an application.  I just can't set up or use the DB diagrams.

Answer (score 3):

The suggestion from Randy led to a resolution. In looking at the DB files properties there was no owner.

[image]

I tried to set the owner to my Windows logon, but that led to an error because there was an existing reference to it.  Then, I set the owner to sa and that worked.

[image]

The diagrams are now accessible.

[image]

The only remaining question concerns a possible conflict with the owner of some objects assigned to my Windows login and the files owned by sa.

Comment: I followed this method and gained access to the create diagrams functionality.  Ways of changing Database Owner are also described at https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-change-database-owners-in-sql-server/#:~:text=First%2C%20let%20us%20understand%20the%20process%20of%20changing,which%20is%20next%20to%20the%20Owner%20text%20box.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend database properties > Select File > Select on Owner > Select your system account, set it, then Click on OK.

Comment: I did some editing ("try" seems to imply a debugging experiment, the result of which you want to know before being able to answer - and for that a comment should have been used). I am not sure about the seemingly orphaned word "set" in your phrasing. Please review.